# Show modal based on PHP variable

Tags: php, html

I am having issues with displaying a modal when a user types a duplicate email or username, I have defined a boolean to store true when the modal should be shown and false when not. Even when I type a new username and email, the modal is still being shown and i am really confused why.

PHP:

```
if($checkUser->rowCount() > 0 || $checkEmail->rowCount() > 0){
        $showModal = true;
    }else{
        $showModal = false;
```

HTML:

```
<?php if($showModal===false): ?>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Register" readonly="readonly"/>
            <?php else: ?>
            <input type="" id="submit" name="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Register" readonly="readonly"/>
                  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Registration Error!</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>You have entered a Username or Email Address which has already been registered!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

I remove the type 'submit' from the modal input as it was causing the modal to break as the page was being refreshed.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: We cannot help you, because your question is incomplete. We don't know how the two piece of code exactly relate. Are they in the same file? We also don't know what `$checkUser` and `$checkEmail` do.

Comment: checkUser and checkEmail are queries, this is clear through the use of ->rowCount() and yes, they are in the same file.

Comment: Ah, you're using PDO. No, that wasn't obvious. You're aware that PHP is executed on the server, not in the client browser? This seems to be at the root of your problem, if I'm allowed to have a guess.

Comment: If every answer on this site wasn't written in a snobby manner, then maybe there might be more programmers to go around. Yes, I know PHP is server side, regardless of if PDO is being used